# How can I pull multiple variable values from a string (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string

For example:

```
$string = "AND (pr.StatusCode <> 'U') AND ((pr.pkBrand = 9) OR (pr.pkBrand = 70)) AND ((pr.pkCategory = 55) OR (pr.pkCategory = 56)) AND (pr.StatusCode <> 'D')";
```

I would need to pull the values associate with pkBrand i.e. 9 & 70 to push into an array for use elsewhere and the values of pkCategory i.e. 55 & 56 into a separate array again for use elsewhere.

How can I do this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is much less concise but it aims to work regardless of the field name:

```
<?php
$string = "AND (pr.StatusCode <> 'U') AND ((pr.pkBrand = 9) OR (pr.pkBrand = 70)) AND ((pr.pkCategory = 55) OR (pr.pkCategory = 56)) AND (pr.StatusCode <> 'D')";
$newString=trim(str_replace(')','',str_replace('(','',str_replace('OR','',str_replace('AND','',$string)))));
$tab=explode('pr.',$newString);
foreach($tab as $value) {
 $value=trim(str_replace(' ','',str_replace('\'','',$value)));
 $tab2[]=$value;
}
/*echo '<pre>';
var_dump($tab2);
echo '</pre>';*/
$operators=['!=','<>','<','>','='];
foreach ($tab2 as $index=>$value) {
 foreach ($operators as $operator) {
    $found=0;
    $explode=explode($operator,$value);
     if (count($explode)==1) {}//not the good one
     else {
      $found=1;
      break;
     }
 }
 if ($found==1) $newTab[$explode[0]][$index]=$explode[1];
}


echo '<pre>';
var_dump($newTab);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Will give you :

```
array(3) {
  ["StatusCode"]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "U"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  ["pkBrand"]=>
  array(2) {
    [2]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "70"
  }
  ["pkCategory"]=>
  array(2) {
    [4]=>
    string(2) "55"
    [5]=>
    string(2) "56"
  }
}
```

Comment: your code gives me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ...

for this line $operators = ['!=','<>','<','>','='];

Comment: no error for me. Can you give me the complete error message ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /Users/***/Sites/***/_plugins/site-pages/public/add-a-model-pages/manage-models.php on line 547

line 547 is $operators=['!=','<>','<','>','='];

Comment: ok you certainly use php <5.4. Replace `$operators=['!=','<>','<','>','='];` with `$operators = array('!=','<>','<','>','=');`

Comment: You are correct the server runs 5.3.26, your revised code runs a treat

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
$string = "AND (pr.StatusCode <> 'U') AND ((pr.pkBrand = 9) OR (pr.pkBrand = 70)) AND ((pr.pkCategory = 55) OR (pr.pkCategory = 56)) AND (pr.StatusCode <> 'D')";
preg_match_all("/pr.pkBrand = (\d+)|pr.pkCategory = (\d+)/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The `$matches` array will look like this:

`array(4) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(14) "pr.pkBrand = 9"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "9"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(15) "pr.pkBrand = 70"
    [1] =>
    string(2) "70"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(18) "pr.pkCategory = 55"
    [1] =>
    string(0) ""
    [2] =>
    string(2) "55"
  }
  [3] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(18) "pr.pkCategory = 56"
    [1] =>
    string(0) ""
    [2] =>
    string(2) "56"
  }
}`

Then you can extract the values you want from this.